# plotly.js: how to access data other than x, y on click event

Tags: javascript, plotly

below is the code in the [document of plotly.js dealing with click events](https://plot.ly/javascript/click-events/)

```
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
    d3 = Plotly.d3,
    N = 16,
    x = d3.range(N),
    y = d3.range(N).map( d3.random.normal() ),
    data = [ { x:x, y:y, type:'scatter',
            mode:'markers', marker:{size:16} } ],
    layout = {
        hovermode:'closest',
        title:'Click on Points'
     };

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
    var pts = '';
    for(var i=0; i < data.points.length; i++){
        pts = 'x = '+data.points[i].x +'\ny = '+
            data.points[i].y.toPrecision(4) + '\n\n';
    }
    alert('Closest point clicked:\n\n'+pts);
});
```

via `plotly_click` event, I can access the data through the point values `x` and `y`. but I want to get the other fields than these. Assume I change the above data in a suitable way for `plotly.js` as

```
var N = 5,
    x = d3.range(N),
    y = d3.range(N).map( d3.random.normal() ),
    text = d3.range(N).map( function() {return "hello";} ),
    data = [ {x: x, y: y, text: text, type:"scatter", mode: "markers"} ];
```

in this case, is there a way to access `text` attribute in `plotly_click` event? basically I want to open new tab with url containing additional information (like `text` field).

Additionally, I wander how to make data with hidden fields (other than `text`) so that I use `text` for tooltips when hover, and other field for the click event. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm interested in doing this too.

Comment: @David: See answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the data associated with your click event via `d` from `function(d)`.

The index of the clicked point can be retrieved via `d.points[0].pointNumber`.

`d.points[0].fullData` and `d.points[0].data` contain your text as an array.

`d.points[0].data` contains additional attributes (e.g. `freetext` in the snippet below).

```js
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var x = [0, 1, 2];
var y = [0, 1, 0];
var text = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var freetext = ['One Is a Lonely Number', 'two is better than one', 'three is a lucky number'];
var data = [{x: x,
        y: y,
        text: text,
        freetext: freetext,
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: 'markers',
        marker: {size: 64}}];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

myPlot.on('plotly_click', function (d) {
    window.alert('Here is the text associated with your point:\n' + d.points[0].data.text[d.points[0].pointNumber] + '\n\nbut you can also get any other info as well:\n' + d.points[0].data.freetext[d.points[0].pointNumber]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```